# How to Read a Video stream from OTG input in react-native (expo) - reduce the frame-rate, convert to grayscale and display it?

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg, expo

I am very new to React. I'm trying to build an android application with React Native (Expo) which requires reading a video input from an HDMI to USB converter + an OTG cable.

[Video Capture Card or HDMI to USB 2.0 Converter – Live Streaming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOfPG.jpg)

I need to :

- a) read the input video stream
- b) reduce the frame rate of the video to 1fps
- c) convert it to grayscale
- d) display it.

Can anyone please suggest to me an idea on how to accomplish the above steps?

1. What is the standard method/process for this job?
2. Is there any tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: found the solution? if yes, please help with answer as I need to do the same

Comment: how were you able to read the input from OTG in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video) component

- a) can read video stream
- b) can change playrate
- c) can convert it to grayscale/FilterType.MONOCHROME (only available on
  ios devices)
- d) can display it.

Here is a brief article about [Video Live Streaming with React Native](https://medium.com/syntx-io/video-live-streaming-with-react-native-98a0f6354077) and [youtube videos about react-native-video](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=react%20native%20videos)

If possible, recording video directly at 1 fps with grayscale effect can be quite efficient. If this isn't possible, it may be nice to send the final version of the video to the application by performing the operations on the video on the server side. (reducing fps rate and adding grayscale effect on server) Server side operation can cause some delay.